# Dynamically create img element from canvas

Tags: javascript, jquery, canvas

I have a canvas which I wish to manipulate. I want to use a jQuery plugin that requires an img-element as input. Can I dynamically create an img-element from canvas using javascript?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Canvas2Image](http://www.nihilogic.dk/labs/canvas2image/) can convert a canvas to a variety of image types, might be what you're looking for.

Comment: Thanks. I stumbled across this earlier but was in too much of hurry to notice that it actually does want I want. Thank you for mentioning!